# I'm loading a .DLL in runtime, but always i stop the solution in debug mode and start again the program will crash

Tags: vb6

I'm using a device in my vb6 program and i loaded the .dll of this device during runtime in a module.

I need to declare all the methods of the .dll

Example:

```
Declare Function FTRGetParam Lib "FtrAPI.DLL" _
    (ByVal Param As Long, ByRef value As Any) As Integer
```

But when i enter in this module again in the next execution, the program will crash and i must to close the Visual Studio IDE.

Any Idea?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @SlLaks: Probably none.  See my note to the OP.

Comment: This usually means that you have the Declare statement wrong.  The usual culprit is one of the parameter types.  Are you translating from a C++ declaration?

Comment: I receive no error... the program only crashes.  About the declaration, i think this is a default way to declare methods of some .dll files in other language.